# What control circuit element will control an ESC while doing bench testing?

Tags: brushless-motor, esc

While doing bench testing of motor and prop combinations what simple device would I use in the circuit to properly control the ESC for the full range of power from 0% to 100% ?
I have seen a few videos where bench testing is demonstrated to measure the thrust and power usage of a brushless motor and propeller. Typically the control of the ESC is done with a very small device attached to the ESC? What is that device? (I find it hard to believe it as simple as a rheostat, or is it?)

Comment: what input does the ESC expect?

Comment: I expect the input signal for all ESCs used to control the speed of the motor on multirotors is a PWM.

Answer (score 1):

To Control an ESC, or rather, give a control signal, one generally uses some kind of micro controller (arduino, esp32, Ti c2000, STM, countless others) with a ESC dependent control signal. The mcus themselves don't have to be large, they simply need to be able to provide a signal usually at 5v, which is trivial for them.

Some (most) of them require a PWM signal, such as the [escons](https://www.maxongroup.com/maxon/view/product/control/4-Q-Servokontroller/466023)

> The ESCON Module 24/2 is a small-sized, powerful 4-quadrant PWM OEM servo controller for the highly efficient control of permanent magnet-activated brushed DC motors and brushless EC motors up to approximately 48 Watts.

Others like the [espos](https://www.maxongroup.com/maxon/view/product/control/4-Q-Servokontroller/466023) are controlled over a communcations protocol such as CAN.

> The EPOS4 Compact 24/1.5 CAN is a dynamic, ready-to-connect positioning controller in a compact design. Designed for use with brushed DC motors with encoders and brushless EC motors (BLDC) with Hall sensors and encoders up to 36 W / 108 W.

If you're in the professional area, and in hobby areas

Things like the [turnigy](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/turnigy-multistar-30a-blheli-32-4-in-1-race-spec-esc-w-f4-fc-osd-bec-2-4s.html)

Are also done with PWM,

Here is a post on using an e[sc with arduino](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/123479/how-to-use-turnigy-multistar-esc-with-generic-microcontroller).

Answer (score 0):

If your ESC uses servo-like control signals, the you want to send it a servo PWM pulse, generally at 50hz (20ms) with a pulse between 1ms (5% duty cycle) which is full reverse, and 2ms (10% duty cycle) which is full forward.  You can generate that signal with a microcontroller or a cheap servo tester.  Search amazon or aliexpress for 'serve tester' and you will find things like this, [https://www.amazon.com/ICQUANZX-Aluminum-Consistency-Controler-Helicopter/dp/B081D5VHVY/ref=sr_1_6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B081D5VHVY)